# UTF8 Text Encoding - Windows Phone 8.1 C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have an api which returns a UTF8 string but on my app the TextBlock that shows this string is using other encoding than UTF8. How can I deal with such a problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, what are you doing with the string to display it? How are you converting it, or passing it to the UI?

Comment: I assigned it to a property which is bind with a TextBlock. My response is a json string which being parsed using JsonObject^

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.textblock.text(v=vs.105).aspx) property? What's the exact data type of the string you use to set the property? What's the `JsonObject` method that gives you the data. How is the `JsonObject`being created?

Comment: I'm using the     `JsonObject::Parse(jsonItem->Stringify())->GetNamedString("ITEM")` in order to get the variable. The property has type IObservableMap.

Comment: Sorry, It's a child JsonArray item. `JsonArray^ jsonObject = JsonArray::Parse(string); for (const auto &jsonItem : jsonObject)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75135/discussion-between-swe-and-bames53).

Comment: Can you post the http reponse headers that result from your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion I'm guessing that the HttpClient object is performing an incorrect conversion due to either the server failing to specify an encoding, or specifying the wrong encoding. Check the content encoding and content type response headers.

Comment: My API returns the response in UTF8. How can HttpClient be able to read it as UTF8?

Comment: @SWE Have you done as I suggested and checked the content encoding and content type response headers returned by the web server in the http reponse?

Comment: Yeah! Server is a nodejs API which uses json type an utf-8 encoding. Still client doesn't seem to be respond to this.

Comment: @SWE So you get: `Content-Type: application/json` or `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: Finally worked. It was a restify letter casing problem. The correct was `res.charSet('utf-8');` instead of `res.charset('utf-8');`. @bames53 Thank you for your help!